# Setting up multiple modules python appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Using python 2.7 and Google app engine I am building a website composed of multiple modules.

By that I mean that I am looking to build each module in an app like fashion.

To achieve my goal I have set up multiple *.yaml files using the includes (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Includes).
It seems to do what I want until... none of the secondary modules are loaded... I could play around with the 'import' loader in python locally, but I am looking for something less hacky that would work with the app engine deployer (and on the Google server).
Basically my problem is that I do not know how to 'include' all python modules (as they live in separate directories as ruled by different yaml). I looked over on the doc and it does not seem to be explained.

I am NOT looking to run them as separated modules, which could be a way of handling it.
I could be opened to it but I run into a similar situation with that approach though: how to I include/package the common code in each module?

As I have nothing working I did not include sample code or yaml.

Thank you for your help!

@TimHoffman & @EzequielMuns

Thank you, I implemented the change suggested:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append("[absolute_path_to_be_sure]/used_app")
```

And got:

```
  File "[...]/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 903, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named DefaultHandler
```

Seems the sandboxing gets in the way (the function that returns this seems hard coded).
The `Defaulthandler` is a python class that live in a module at the root of `used_app`. I got the error trying to import it.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
 - main_app
   - app.yaml
   - MyApp.py
   - Handler.py
 - used_app
   - DefaultHandler.py
   - include.yaml (though I am not sure it is useful to me right now)
```

Where `Handler` inherits `DefaultHandler` for example.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your question making very specific where you're referring to python modules and where you are referring to [Google App Engine Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/). 

Can you at least post the directory structure you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using the include.yaml isn't doing anything. It's meant to include more handlers and other limited amounts of config into your main `app.yaml`.

It's my experience that all your code needs to live *under* the main app directory, but you can have symlinks if you must (this is especially useful with 3rd party libraries). So why not try to have `used_app` inside the main app directory.

For reference, I have set up these two layouts before with success:

```
appdir/
    app.yaml
    main.py
    lib/
    package/
        __init__.py
        module.py
```

Here there is no need to modify `sys.path` to access `package.module` as the `appdir` is in the PYTHONPATH.

Occasionally I've had to include 3rd party libraries into a `lib` subdirectory, which then needs to be added to `sys.path` via `appengine_config.py`:

```
appdir/
    app.yaml
    main.py
    appengine_config.py
    lib/
        awesomelibrary/
            __init__.py
            thirdpartymodule.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        module.py
```

With `appengine_config.py`:

```
import sys, os
base = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(base, 'lib'))
```

Thereby making `awesomelibrary.thirdpartymodule` importable (and any other packages/modules under `lib/`).

Comment: Just to point out, the code for a module can live outside the appdir(Mine lives in a sibling dir), without having any symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your paths in appengine_config  then import as required in each handler. `appengine_confgi.py` is loaded prior to any of you code being imported.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig